# CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected: Bad file descriptor Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am going to train my yolo model by below code.

```
! darknet/darknet detector train custom_data/labelled_data.data darknet/cfg/yolov3_custom.cfg custom_weight/darknet53.conv.74 -dont_show
```

Then it shows an error as below

```
CUDA status Error: file: ./src/dark_cuda.c : () : line: 39 : build time: Sep  8 2021 - 06:14:34 

CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected
Darknet error location: ./src/dark_cuda.c, check_error, line #70
CUDA Error: no CUDA-capable device is detected: Bad file descriptor
```

First I tried the code using GPU. But after exceed the limit of GPU I tried it with the TPU.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: You can not run CUDA code using a TPU. It requires a CUDA GPU. What you are trying to do is impossible

Answer (score 1):

TPU aren't CUDA enabled

Try the following snippet just to make sure

```
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)
```